# ML_AGENT POCA Training, One side learning well, other side bad

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, ml-agent, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I am trying to train competitive 2 vs 2 hockey game. It is symetrical game. I am using MA-POCA. My problem one of the teams learning very well but other side is very bad. How this can happen? MA-POCA algorthm using self-play and if one side is playing good, other team also should play well because it is using old policy. But this is not happening.

I also want to ask you one more thing. I add “footballer begining side” input which is 0 or 1. I do this because agent can start right sided or left sided so it should know which post he should score. Should I remove this king of input? Thanks for answers.

I check my team_id’s → They should be different so I arrange like that

I am sharing my config file

behaviors:
SoccerAgent:
trainer_type: poca
hyperparameters:
batch_size: 1024
buffer_size: 10240
learning_rate: 0.0003
beta: 0.005
epsilon: 0.2
lambd: 0.95
num_epoch: 3
learning_rate_schedule: constant
network_settings:
normalize: false
hidden_units: 512
num_layers: 2
vis_encode_type: simple
goal_conditioning_type: none
reward_signals:
extrinsic:
gamma: 0.99
strength: 1.0
keep_checkpoints: 5
max_steps: 5000000
time_horizon: 1024
summary_freq: 20000
self_play:
save_steps: 100000
team_change: 500000
swap_steps: 10000
window: 10
play_against_latest_model_ratio: 0.5
initial_elo: 1200.0